# coreplot multiple axis

Tags: ios, ipad, core-plot

Im using coreplot to draw a graph. The graph should have a common x Axis and multiple y axis.
I got multiple y axis by creating multiple plot spaces

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace2 = [[[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init] autorelease];
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace3 = [[[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Now how to plot points in each of the plot spaces?

The plotting is happening only in Default plot space.

How to change the plot space dynamically? So that plotting is done with respect to the other plotspaces x & y range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each plot is assigned to a plot space. Either add the plots to the graph using the `-addPlot:toPlotSpace:` method or change the plot space after it is already in a graph using the `plotSpace` property.